# when i want to create one instance in KV language it creates two

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

When i try to create one instance in kivy file (Board in my case), kv language file create it twice. I put print(self) in order to show it you. You can see, here two widgets(Board class instances) are created instead of one. And all functions are called twice. Once for each widget. But when i create it inside DrawApp class, it creates in once, as it should be.

My question is - why does it happen, maybe my code have problems? I've tried to fix it, but i just can't.

python file **draw.py**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core import window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

kivy.require('2.0.0')

Builder.load_file('draw.kv')

Window.clearcolor = (0.1,0.1,0.1,1)
Window.size = (860, 500)


class MainLayout(Widget):
    def draw_point(self, touch):
        print(self)
        self.ids.board_id.canvas.add(Color( rgb=self.ids.board_id.pen_color ))
        touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y), width=self.ids.board_id.pen_size)
        self.ids.board_id.canvas.add(touch.ud['line'])
    def draw_line(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x,touch.y]
    def clear_board(self):
        print(self)
        self.ids.board_id.canvas.clear()



class Board(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(self)
        self.num = 1
        self.pen_color = (1,1,0)
        self.pen_size = 5

class Button1(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(self)
        self.num = 1
        self.pen_color = (1,1,0)
        self.pen_size = 5


class DrawApp(App):   
    print("=======") 
    x = Button1()
    print("=======") 
    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DrawApp().run()
```

kivy file **draw.kv**

```
<Button>
    font_size: root.height/2.5


<MainLayout>
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            text: 'dark'
            size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
            pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}
        Button:
            size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
            pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":0.9}
        Button:
            text: 'clear'
            size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
            pos_hint: {"left":0, "top":1}
            on_release: root.clear_board()
        Button:
            size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
            pos_hint: {"left":0, "top":0.9}

        Board:
            id: board_id
            pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}
            size: root.width, root.height
            on_touch_down: root.draw_point(args[1])
            on_touch_move: root.draw_line(args[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i found my mistake.
This is because **kv** file is loaded twice.

1. Automatically as my class app has the name `DrawApp(App)`, and kv **draw.kv**
2. With a builder `Builder.load_file('draw.kv')`